# Difference in notation for radial component of electric field formula

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, notation

Apologies if this is a trivial question, but it is a notation confusion lingering in the back of my head. In the electric field formula, I'm having confused going back and forth between $$\frac{\vec{r}}{r^{3}}$$ and $$\frac{\hat{r}}{r^{2}}$$. When do you use which version of the radial component of the electric field, especially when it comes to plugging in numerical values or when you're using the formula in proofs and derivations like in divergence calculations and others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're exactly the same, so you can use either one.

Specifically, $\hat{r}$ is a vector that points in the same direction as $\vec{r}$, but with unit length. The way you get this unit vector $\hat{r}$ from the corresponding non-unit vector $\vec{r}$ is by dividing by its length. (Does that make sense?)
$$\hat{r} = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}\quad\text{(by definition)}$$
From there it's easy enough to see how
$$\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2} = \frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}$$

Comment: So, would we say electric field decreases inversely by a degree of 3 or by 2?

Comment: It is called “inverse square”. Take the magnitude of either one to see this.

Comment: True, thank you!